# Loading Hibernate properties outside context isn't working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm facing some strange problem here and right now I'm stuck. I've read some other posts on this regards and some of then helped me to configure my enviroment, but for some reason that I couldn't find out why it is not working.

I need to place the `hibernate.connection.url, hibernate.connection.username and hibernate.connection.password` properties outside my WAR file to make easier to configure theese parameters when the system is deployed on different servers. So after digging over the Google I find this solution:

applicationContext.xml:

```
...
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="br.myapp.DataBaseConfig"/>
```

And the class `DataBaseConfig`

```
public class DataBaseConfig extends AnnotationSessionFactoryBean {
    private final BaseConfig baseConfig = new BaseConfig();  

    public DataBaseConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        Properties dbConfig = new Properties();
        dbConfig = baseConfig.getPropertiesFile("myPropertiesFile");

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Enumeration<Object> props = dbConfig.keys();

        while ( props.hasMoreElements() ){
            String key = (String)props.nextElement();
            config.setProperty( key , dbConfig.getProperty(key) ); 
        }
        config.addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(); 
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file looks like:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="br.myapp.model.SomeClass1" />
        <mapping class="br.myapp.model.SomeClass2" />
        <mapping class="br.myapp.model.SomeClass3" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My `myPropertiesFile` is:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1524:MyDB
hibernate.connection.username=user
hibernate.connection.password=passpass
hibernate.default_schema=myschema
hibernate.connection.oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#I'm usign c3p0 to pool connections
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=3000
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

With this enviroment when I'm trying to get something from the database without success on this way:

```
final SomeClass1 sm = repository.find(SomeClass1.class)
            .where( Restrictions.eq( "someField" , varFromWebForm ) )
            .uniqueResult();
```

But `sm` always returns `null`, and on the console there is no query printed even with `hibernate.show_sql=true` setted.

The strange thing is that when I change the configurations on my `applicationContext.xml` file like this

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to this

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1524:MyDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passpass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">myschema</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <mapping class="br.myapp.model.SomeClass1" />
        <mapping class="br.myapp.model.SomeClass2" />
        <mapping class="br.myapp.model.SomeClass3" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

All works fine. So it is like the code that read the properties and inject it on the Configuration to Hibernate (`DataBaseConfig`) is not working properly.
Can someone point me out what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

There is no exceptions on the console. it just doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**

This is the log from the apache server. I'm using VRaptor as controllerManager and the only things that appear when I call my method to do the query is the requisition to the controller nothing else, therefore I think that it is not important to put it here.

I've try to put the log here but the SO doesn't let me because it extrapolate the characters limit for a question so, here is a link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/cASD7EPu

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my own question by changing the way I read the configurations. The waqy I was doing does not work and I couldn't find out why. Which is like this:

```
@Override
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    Properties dbConfig = new Properties();
    dbConfig = baseConfig.getPropertiesFile("myPropertiesFile");

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Enumeration<Object> props = dbConfig.keys();

    while ( props.hasMoreElements() ){
        String key = (String)props.nextElement();
        config.setProperty( key , dbConfig.getProperty(key) ); 
    }
    config.addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(); 
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

So I was reading the [Hibernate#Configuration docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) and find the method `configure(File file)`. Then I took the `hibernate.cfg.xml` out of my context and put it on my configs directory (which I get from a Util class of my project) and it work fine. The final method is like:

```
@Override
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.configure(
             new File( BaseConfig.CONFIG_BASE 
                        + File.separator 
                        + "hibernate.cfg.xml" ) 
    );
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(); 
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

And now it is working fine. I would like to find out why the previous configuration did not work to understand. This is not the best solution but solved my problem.

I've a friend here that always says: "It isn't an ugly solution until someone else show a better one!". So for now I will stick with this one.

Thanks to the ones who came here and tryied to help me.

I will not mark this answer as the right one for some time to see if someone else can show me a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say (`DataBaseConfig`) is not working properly : Do you have somes `Exceptions` and a `StackTrace` returned by the Spring Container. Try To launch your app in debug/trace mode to see what happen exactly.

Comment: No there isn't any exceptions on the log and I've put all my appenders to DEBUG state it simple doesn't do the query. I did not see the code of hibernate but it seems like the `session-factory` session of the hibernate.cfg.xml is overrinding the properties. But more strange than that is on the console I see the info the it could connect to the database.

Comment: Could you put your new log now cause it's seems to me that you do not set well your configuration in the first one, so Hibernate put into your configuration the default one. Is't important for you to use java based spring configuration ? if not I have another way more flexible at my point of view when the `hibernate.cfg.xml` is note big. I could put you here some code sample. the solution in summary is to configure every thing into the spring `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: I would like to see the fully qualified class name. Just change the log output pattern. For example with log4j : `log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern` and add %c:%L